# how to get address, contact details from url/web site using bing api?

Tags: php, jquery

can anybody help me.
I have some urls/web sites(like www.facebook.com, www.olx.com, www.abc.com.... etc). From the urls i need to get address/contact details using "Bing" api.
I have an api
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=...........
by this im getting website and few details but not showing address and contact details.
this is my code

```
$accountKey = 'XXXX';

$ServiceRootURL =  'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/';
$sitehost = 'facebook';
$WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Web?$format=json&Query=';
$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $sitehost . '\'');
$response = file_get_contents_curl($request,$accountKey,$accountKey);
$jsonobj = json_decode($response,true);

function file_get_contents_curl($url,$user,$pass)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

If you have any solution, please let me know
thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have any code, please let us know.

Comment: $ServiceRootURL =  'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/';
$sitehost = 'facebook New York Fort Jones CA 96032 United States';
//$sitehost = 'facebook CR-V Eleva Village of WI 54738 United States';
$WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Web?$format=json&Query=';
$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $sitehost . '\'');
$response = file_get_contents_curl($request,$accountKey,$accountKey);
$jsonobj = json_decode($response,true);

Comment: please put the code in the question!

Comment: function file_get_contents_curl($url,$user,$pass)
    {
        $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        return $data;
    }